# What subset of Linux does recent WSL support?

Tags: system-calls, portability

I know well Linux but nothing about [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) or Windows. I'm using Linux since 1993, but I never used Windows (and probably won't use it before my retirement, e.g. before 2024, so I am likely to *never* use Windows).

From a Linux programmer's perspective, what are the features (both ABI- and API- wise ...) of recent Linux that WSL does not support well? I guess it is Xorg, Wayland, systemd. But what about [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) or [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) or [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) ? I guess `dlopen` is *obviously* supported by WSL , but I am not sure about `inotify` or `signalfd`?

In other words, where can I find guidance on **how to write WSL friendly Linux applications?** Is there some exhaustive list of system calls (from [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...) supported in WSL? Or examples, and explanations, about Linux libraries or software not running on WSL?

The motivation might be to make my [bismon](http://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) project WSL friendly. I don't want to put a lot of efforts on that (and I even don't want to install Windows or WSL myself). But `bismon` is a Linux app, not a WSL or Windows one.

Comment: WSL is a fake kernel, but only Microsoft know what exactly it supports. It supports most syscall and sysfs and procfs, maybe even fancy linux-specific functions like cgroups and namespace and abstract Unix domain sockets. But I'm pretty sure it doesn't support kernel-mode modules and lots of ioctl for devices. Also I think it will not support mount ext4 or btrfs or xfs, etc.

Comment: But do you know about a complete list of system calls (e.g. an hypothetical 4th column to the table in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) mentionning every system call supported on WSL)? My `bismon` don't do device IO directly (only files and TCP & Unix sockets & pipes). It runs without root privilege.

Comment: Basically, WSL was designed to run a low-level developer supplied "distro", then user applications run on this fake OS, which usually can't run Xorg or systemd, which is common in real OS. Your app, for the best, basically a service that don't need user interface.

Comment: My bismon uses HTTP server side (thru `libonion`) and temporarily GTK. Soon, I won't use GTK and only provide a web interface (thru `libonion`). The rest of `bismon` is about running command-line Linux processes (notably `gcc`). But `dlopen` is *very* important to me. But I use `signalfd` and could want to use `inotify`

Comment: Gtk can be used if it doesn't try to connect to Xorg or Wayland Server(not create a window).

Comment: GTK is not really an issue for me. I will stop using it in 2018 (when all my UI becomes a web one).

Comment: Just write for Linux without need for other services, test it on WSL, it's easy

Comment: @神秘德里克 No, I really don't want to install Windows on my PC. I don't have Windows and I don't want to learn it, so I don't want to *test* WSL (just want to be able to tell people: you might *try* my `bismon` under WSL)

Comment: It's weird that a developer want to develop app for some platform but don't want to touch that platform but stick to a emulator

Comment: I contractually am developing bismon *only* for Linux. But I have partners (in [CHARIOT](http://chariotproject.eu/) research project) who know *nothing* about it. That is the weirdness of H2020 projects. I am trying to propose them several solutions (but I won't learn Windows or WinAPI or WSL myself)

Comment: It's logic problem, not coding problem. You ARE developing for WSL or Windows. Or transfer workload to other people. Period.

Comment: Very good insight. Thanks. So I won't develop for WSL. I was hoping for some existing guidance or specification of WSL. Apparently there is none!

Comment: As my first statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84145/discussion-between-basile-starynkevitch-and-).